# How do I search a constructor objects properties? JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, search

See the way I have made the fam object. I can search for this objects user-names and my webpage will display its weight by using this code.
As far as I know it is more convenient making objects through a constructor as Dog().
I want my function to be able to iterate through all my objects made through the Dog() constructor such as doggo and doggy and display its weight on my webpage when the user search for the dogs name.
How do I do this, if it is even possible?

```
function Dog(name, weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
}

let doggo = new Dog("Spot", "10kg");
let doggy = new Dog("Snoop", "20kg");

const fam = [
    {
        name: "one",
        weight: "1kg"
    },
    {
        name: "two",
        weight: "2kg"
    },
];

function find() {
    var x = String(field.value);
    for (var i = 0; i<fam.length; i++) {
        if (fam[i].name === x) {
            para.textContent = fam[i].weight;
        }
    }
}
btn.addEventListener("click", find);
```

Comment: Put your objects into an array `var dogs =[]; dogs.push(doggo, doggy);` and then iterate over it. You can also consider to add the `break` keyword inside the `if` block in order to exit the `for` block and stop iterate the whole array.

Comment: Just write `const fam = [doggo, doggy];` or `const fam = [new Dog(…), new Dog(…)];` instead of those object literals.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this on the front-end (without using a database) is to add all the objects, in this case the dogs data, inside of an array and then use `filter()` to select the searched object. Finally return the data to the event listener and create the HTML output.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input'),
      btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
      container = document.getElementById('container');
      
var dogs = [
  new Dog("spot", "10kg"),
  new Dog("snoop", "20kg"),
  new Dog("snoopy", "100kg")
]

function Dog(name, weight) {
  this.name = name
  this.weight = weight
}

function find(name) {
   let info = dogs.filter(dog => dog.name === name)
   return info[0]
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  let dogInfo = find(input.value), 
      html = `name: ${dogInfo.name} <br> weight: ${dogInfo.weight}`
  container.innerHTML = html
})
```

```html
<label>Dog name: </label>
<input id="input" type="text" value="spot">
<button id="btn">Show info</button>
<br><br>
<div id="container"></div>
```